# SwiftyJSON parsing data in array of objects

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to get the value for "name" in the tracks section of JSON. The following JSON is from Spotify. I am using SwiftyJSON for parsing the data.

I am able to pull values from the base json. But once I try to pull anything in the "track" section I get errors.

Here is a sample of the code I got working

```
let swiftJSON = try? JSON(data: data)
let addedAT =  swiftJSON!["items"].arrayValue.map {$0["added_at"].stringValue}
print(addedAT)
```

```
{
  "items" : [
    {
      "video_thumbnail" : {
        "url" : null
      },
      "track" : {
        "is_playable" : true,
        "type" : "track",
        "id" : "3F5CgOj3wFlRv51JsHbxhe",
        "track" : true,
        "duration_ms" : 218364,
        "explicit" : true,
        "uri" : "spotify:track:3F5CgOj3wFlRv51JsHbxhe",
        "is_local" : false,
        "artists" : [
          {
            "external_urls" : {
              "spotify" : "https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/artist\/3TVXtAsR1Inumwj472S9r4"
            },
            "uri" : "spotify:artist:3TVXtAsR1Inumwj472S9r4",
            "type" : "artist",
            "href" : "https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/artists\/3TVXtAsR1Inumwj472S9r4",
            "name" : "Drake",
            "id" : "3TVXtAsR1Inumwj472S9r4"
          },
          {
            "external_urls" : {
              "spotify" : "https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/artist\/1URnnhqYAYcrqrcwql10ft"
            },
            "uri" : "spotify:artist:1URnnhqYAYcrqrcwql10ft",
            "type" : "artist",
            "href" : "https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/artists\/1URnnhqYAYcrqrcwql10ft",
            "name" : "21 Savage",
            "id" : "1URnnhqYAYcrqrcwql10ft"
          }
        ],
        "album" : {
          "name" : "Honestly, Nevermind",
          "total_tracks" : 14,
          "external_urls" : {
            "spotify" : "https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/album\/3cf4iSSKd8ffTncbtKljXw"
          },
          "images" : [
            {
              "height" : 640,
              "url" : "https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/ab67616d0000b2738dc0d801766a5aa6a33cbe37",
              "width" : 640
            },
            {
              "height" : 300,
              "url" : "https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/ab67616d00001e028dc0d801766a5aa6a33cbe37",
              "width" : 300
            },
            {
              "height" : 64,
              "url" : "https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/ab67616d000048518dc0d801766a5aa6a33cbe37",
              "width" : 64
            }
          ],
          "artists" : [
            {
              "external_urls" : {
                "spotify" : "https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/artist\/3TVXtAsR1Inumwj472S9r4"
              },
              "uri" : "spotify:artist:3TVXtAsR1Inumwj472S9r4",
              "type" : "artist",
              "href" : "https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/artists\/3TVXtAsR1Inumwj472S9r4",
              "name" : "Drake",
              "id" : "3TVXtAsR1Inumwj472S9r4"
            }
          ],
          "href" : "https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/albums\/3cf4iSSKd8ffTncbtKljXw",
          "release_date_precision" : "day",
          "type" : "album",
          "id" : "3cf4iSSKd8ffTncbtKljXw",
          "album_type" : "album",
          "release_date" : "2022-06-17",
          "uri" : "spotify:album:3cf4iSSKd8ffTncbtKljXw"
        },
        "track_number" : 14,
        "external_ids" : {
          "isrc" : "USUG12204897"
        },
        "episode" : false,
        "external_urls" : {
          "spotify" : "https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/track\/3F5CgOj3wFlRv51JsHbxhe"
        },
        "popularity" : 90,
        "disc_number" : 1,
        "name" : "Jimmy Cooks (feat. 21 Savage)",
        "preview_url" : "https:\/\/p.scdn.co\/mp3-preview\/5feee7c2fed489c933a31ef125aa4ffb5205a457?cid=263c670f8c17484d89d8bd2e6e0964f7",
        "href" : "https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/tracks\/3F5CgOj3wFlRv51JsHbxhe"
      },
      "added_by" : {
        "uri" : "spotify:user:12493212",
        "external_urls" : {
          "spotify" : "https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/user\/12493212"
        },
        "type" : "user",
        "href" : "https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/users\/12493212",
        "id" : "12493212"
      },
      "primary_color" : null,
      "added_at" : "2022-06-28T16:06:35Z",
      "is_local" : false
    },
    {
      "video_thumbnail" : {
        "url" : null
      },
      "track" : {
        "is_playable" : true,
        "type" : "track",
        "id" : "1qMMYpVatbRITKCfq1gasi",
        "track" : true,
        "duration_ms" : 172933,
        "explicit" : true,
        "uri" : "spotify:track:1qMMYpVatbRITKCfq1gasi",
        "is_local" : false,
        "artists" : [
          {
            "href" : "https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/artists\/1RyvyyTE3xzB2ZywiAwp0i",
            "uri" : "spotify:artist:1RyvyyTE3xzB2ZywiAwp0i",
            "name" : "Future",
            "id" : "1RyvyyTE3xzB2ZywiAwp0i",
            "external_urls" : {
              "spotify" : "https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/artist\/1RyvyyTE3xzB2ZywiAwp0i"
            },
            "type" : "artist"
          }
        ],
        "album" : {
          "external_urls" : {
            "spotify" : "https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/album\/6tE9Dnp2zInFij4jKssysL"
          },
          "href" : "https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/albums\/6tE9Dnp2zInFij4jKssysL",
          "release_date" : "2022-04-29",
          "release_date_precision" : "day",
          "artists" : [
            {
              "href" : "https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/artists\/1RyvyyTE3xzB2ZywiAwp0i",
              "uri" : "spotify:artist:1RyvyyTE3xzB2ZywiAwp0i",
              "name" : "Future",
              "id" : "1RyvyyTE3xzB2ZywiAwp0i",
              "external_urls" : {
                "spotify" : "https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/artist\/1RyvyyTE3xzB2ZywiAwp0i"
              },
              "type" : "artist"
            }
          ],
          "name" : "I NEVER LIKED YOU",
          "type" : "album",
          "album_type" : "album",
          "id" : "6tE9Dnp2zInFij4jKssysL",
          "uri" : "spotify:album:6tE9Dnp2zInFij4jKssysL",
          "images" : [
            {
              "height" : 640,
              "width" : 640,
              "url" : "https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/ab67616d0000b27386badd635b69aea887862214"
            },
            {
              "height" : 300,
              "width" : 300,
              "url" : "https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/ab67616d00001e0286badd635b69aea887862214"
            },
            {
              "height" : 64,
              "width" : 64,
              "url" : "https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/ab67616d0000485186badd635b69aea887862214"
            }
          ],
          "total_tracks" : 16
        },
        "track_number" : 5,
        "external_ids" : {
          "isrc" : "USSM12203787"
        },
        "episode" : false,
        "external_urls" : {
          "spotify" : "https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/track\/1qMMYpVatbRITKCfq1gasi"
        },
        "popularity" : 83,
        "disc_number" : 1,
        "name" : "PUFFIN ON ZOOTIEZ",
        "preview_url" : "https:\/\/p.scdn.co\/mp3-preview\/ff3bd626fd7f0bd6af4a429b3119b06ff0aee089?cid=263c670f8c17484d89d8bd2e6e0964f7",
        "href" : "https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/tracks\/1qMMYpVatbRITKCfq1gasi"
      },
      "added_by" : {
        "external_urls" : {
          "spotify" : "https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/user\/12493212"
        },
        "uri" : "spotify:user:12493212",
        "type" : "user",
        "id" : "12493212",
        "href" : "https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/users\/12493212"
      },
      "primary_color" : null,
      "added_at" : "2022-06-28T16:53:13Z",
      "is_local" : false
    }
  ],
  "href" : "https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/playlists\/1nJflwAwbyhpQzKksqwC7H\/tracks?offset=0&limit=100&market=ES&locale=en-US;q=1.0",
  "offset" : 0,
  "previous" : null,
  "limit" : 100,
  "next" : null,
  "total" : 2
}
```

Comment: If you use `Codable` instead of an old 3rd party library it will greatly increase your chances of getting help.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks I will look into codeable.